# Is there an AWS eventbridge rule to notify when a user assumes an admin role and grab cloudwatch logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I want to create an Eventbridge rule to effectively notify me whenever a user assumes an admin role (godlike admin) and also when that particular user is gathering data from cloudwatch logs.

I think these can be 2 rules but i am not sure where to begin. I thought it could be aws.iam and aws.cloudwatch but i am not getting any events sent to my sns endpoint.

Comment: You would get better (or any) answers if you show the rules that you're using.